# generate color triangle

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to generate a triangle with a background colored in rgb colors. This is used to display color values.

I could find out how to calcuale positions in such a triangle

```
function [x,y] = RGBtoCartCoordXY(R, G, B)
RGB = R + G + B;
r = R / RGB; g = G / RGB; b = B / RGB;
XYr = [-0.5; -0.5]; XYb = [+0.5; -0.5]; XYg = [+0.0; +0.5];
xy = (r * XYr + b * XYb + g * XYg) / ( r + g + b );
x = xy(1); y = xy(2);
```

but my approach to paint such a triangle with points in a plot was not very successful and it takes very long for a usefull number of points (here > 100000)

[image]

It seems as if the points have a shadow and i want no white space in the background. Appart from that I want this plot to be as fast as possible, since I want to plot a simple curve on top - which is the actual information in the plot.
EDIT:

The plot is based on this code:

```
for r = linspace(0,1,points)
    for g = linspace(0,1,points)
        for b = linspace(0,1,points)
            index = index + 1;            
            RBGtriple(index, :) = [r g b];
        end
    end
end

for k = 1:size(RBGtriple,1)
    R = RBGtriple(k,1);
    G = RBGtriple(k,2);
    B = RBGtriple(k,3);
    [x y] = RGBtoCartCoordXY(R,G,B);
    xaxis(k) = x;
    data(k) = y;
end

hold on;
for k = 1:size(RBGtriple,1)
    hplot = plot (xaxis(k), data(k));
    set(hplot, ...
        'Marker', 'square', ...
        'LineStyle','none' , ...
        'MarkerSize' ,3 , ...
        'LineWidth' , 0.1, ...
        'MarkerEdgeColor',RBGtriple(k, :) , ...
        'MarkerFaceColor',RBGtriple(k, :));   
end
hold off;
```

Comment: Which function do you use to plot? And what are your R,G,B input values?

Comment: As shown in the enhanced question he rgb values are equal distributed between 0 an 1 and the plot is done with `plot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a color value for all points in the plane, why do you not take each point an calculate the color value, but instead take a color value and calculate the point where it should appear? Apparently, none of your color input values produces an `xy` of [-.49,-.49], so the red marker at [-.5,-.5] is alone in its region.

Also, you are plotting individual points consecutively, which of course is not fast. (You have matrices growing inside loops in the first two thirds of the code you posted, but I guess the slowest part is the final section). Try creating a matrix of the values you want to show first, then display it.

Try this code:

```
imgsize = 500;
for i=1:length(xaxis),
    m(1+floor((xaxis+0.5)*imgsize),1+floor((data+0.5)*imgsize),:)=RGBtriple(i,:);
end
image(m);
```

For me, this (or similar code adapted from yours) produces a triangle with similar color distribution, but turned 90° and with the default black background.

Comment: This only gives me a blue square with 50x50 pixels. m contains only values 0 or 1 whereas RGBtriple contains values of colors.

Comment: Indeed, it has to be `m(1+floor((xaxis(k)+0.5)*imgsize),1+floor((data(k)+0.5)*imgsize),:)=RGBtriple(k,:)`. It gives a nice triangle. But I think I have to find a way to iterate over the points of the triangle directly, because with a high resolution black points in the triangle still remain.

Answer (score 1):

If there is anyone wondering about it, I found a incredibly easy solution in the book 'Computational Colour Science using MATLAB' to plot RGB triangle:

```
xy=[0 0; 1 0; 0.5 sqrt(3)/2];
col=[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1];
patch('Vertices',xy, 'Faces',[1:size(xy,1)], 'EdgeColor','none','FaceVertexCData', col,'FaceColor','interp');
axis off
text(xy(1,1), xy(1,2)-0.05,'Vertice 1','HorizontalAlignment', 'center')
text(xy(2,1), xy(2,2)-0.05,'Vertice 2','HorizontalAlignment', 'center')
text(xy(3,1), xy(3,2)+0.05,'Vertice 3','HorizontalAlignment', 'center')
```

[RGB color triangle matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMlhQ.jpg)